# I don't want my elements to be reassigned when the element set as IsVisible="false" has been changed to IsVisible="false"

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm creating a mobile app using .net MAUI
I'm hiding one element and making it visible in button action. That time other elements got rearrange.

```
<VerticalStackLayout
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    Padding="30,0"
    Spacing="25">
    <Image
        x:Name="ThinkWing"
        Source="pngwing.png"
        WidthRequest="200"
        IsVisible="false"
        Aspect="AspectFit"
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
   <Label
       Text="Welcome! "
       Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
       SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />
   <Button
        x:Name="CounterBtn"
        Text="Hit me if you can" 
        SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
        BorderColor="Black"
        BorderWidth="3"
        BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
        TextColor="Black"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

This is in my XAML file and I change  IsVisible="true" when the button is clicked.

So what happens is. When my app loaded I can see the Label and Button center of my screen. When the button clicked, the hidden image has appeared in top so that other two elements got pushed down. But I don't want this to be happen like this unless it can allocate the space for hidden element when the screen loaded.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you thought about using a `Grid` instead of `VerticalStackLayout`? You can assign fixed heights to the rows so that the layout stays the same even if you hide or show things like `Label` and `Button` that are in a row,

Comment: Thanks! I'm in learning phase. Dont mind asking can't we do that using VerticalLayout? or we can achieve that by only using grid?

Comment: What you would have to do is add something like a `Frame` element to reserve the `RequestedHeight` and put the hide/show element inside that frame. Otherwise `VerticalStackLayout` is going to "help you out" by compensating for the elements that you hide as you have observed.

Comment: I tried Grid and adding a Frame but both gives me a separations visible. Actually my requirement is When I click the hit button a think bubble should popup just before the Welcome label. It was fine as I mentioned in the VerticalLayout but the only thing is the elements rearranging. I would be so much helpful if there is a way someone shows me. Also I'm not too good in using grids. Maybe we can so this using grids but I dont know how.

Comment: Several ways to achieve this. The easiest way I think is to use a [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-8.0) to wrap your image with Border stroke set as transparent.

Comment: BTW, other layouts such as [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout?view=net-maui-8.0) or [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0) can also work as both of them can place inner controls at a fixed position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a "hidden image" that should be superimposed on top of another element in response to `Clicked` without changing the `VerticalStackLayout`.

[image: show hidden element]

One basic strategy would be to use a `Grid` control to reserve the vertical space. The behavior of `Grid` is that the the elements you add to a row or column will "layer up" on each other instead of "flow" as is the case with `VerticalStackLayout`.

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    Padding="30,0"
    Spacing="25">
    <Grid HeightRequest="60">
        <Label
            x:Name="labelWelcome"
                Text="Welcome! "
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />
        <Frame                    
            x:Name="ThinkWing"
            BorderColor="Transparent"
            Padding="1"
            IsVisible="False"
            BackgroundColor="White">
            <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" />
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="CounterBtn"
        Text="Hit me if you can" 
        SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
        Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
        BorderColor="Black"
        BorderWidth="3"
        BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
        TextColor="Black"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to know things are moving forward! If you feel that your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please consider marking the '✓' to accept it.